# Why are Java naming conventions not enforced?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Java has strong naming conventions for class, method, field and variable names.
For instance:

- Class names should start with an upper case character
- Methods, fields, and variable names should start with a lower case character

The JDK has only few exceptions to these two rules.

But a convention is not a syntax rule, and therefore classes like the following compile without errors (C# programmers would be happy anyway):

```
 public class string {
      private char[] C;
      public int Length() { return C.length; }
 }
```

But the gap between a convention and a syntax rule inevitable leads to violations of the convention by beginners which then leads to lengthy explanations about naming conventions.

If the *most fundamental naming conventions* (like the one cited above) would be part of the syntax then the Java compiler would enforce them and automatically educate those beginners.

So here is the question:

From the Java language designers point of view: Is there any good reason to leave a gap between syntax and naming conventions which should never be violated? Are there any meaningful use cases for namings (of classes, methods, fields, variables) which violate the convention but make sense beyond the convention?

Comment: Because they're conventions.

Comment: I can think of one use case for violating the conventions: code obfuscation. (Granted, most obfuscators work at the byte code level, while you are presumably talking about the source code.)

Comment: @EJP of course. But why should I want a convention which should not be violated and not make it a syntax rule?

Comment: Why should I want a syntax rule that isn't required to make the language unambiguous? Clearly you've never done compiler design or language design. You don't need arbitrary rules, you need disambiguating rules. The history of programming languages shows that very clearly.

Comment: And it's extremely questionable whether it would really educate anybody. Beginners have a hard enough time with syntax errors already.

Comment: see this code:) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690135/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-java-code

Comment: @EJP 1. excuse me, this question was not about my knowledge of compiler design or compiler design in general. I just asked why a naming convention which should never be violated is not better made part of the syntax. 2. sometimes it is better if the compiler tells the rookie that she used a wrong classname than some strong-opinioned colleague.

Comment: Although a cursory reading may suggest that this is opinion-based, I think at least this second question can be answered without opinion: *"Are there any meaningful use cases for namings (of classes, methods, fields, variables) which violate the convention but make sense beyond the convention?"*

Comment: I don't understand your 'excuse me'. The question is *about* compiler design, and language design, and nothing else. Naming conventions are not syntax rules; and syntax rules are carefully designed by the people who do it so as to be non-redundant. Otherwise you can easily end up with a self-inconsistent language specification. But the real answer to your question is that it's too late to even ask. Backwards compatibility says so.

Answer (score 3):

The conventions were written long after the language was defined so they could be retrofitted without breaking compatibility. The problem with conventions are they involve taste. e.g. spaces or tabs, using `$` as a variable name, starting field names with `m_` or `_` etc. even wither to add `get` and `set` to getters and setters (which I prefer not to)

Java actually allows you to do things which would make C programmer feel queasy.  Why they allowed this I don't know, but I assume they didn't want to limit adoption by imposing more rules than really needed.

Note this is a piece of Java code is valid due to the use of a character which probably shouldn't be allowed but is.

```
for (char c⁯‮h = 0; c⁯‮h < Character.MAX_VALUE; c⁯‮h++)
    if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c⁯‮h) && !Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c⁯‮h))
        System.out.printf("%04x <%s>%n", (int) c⁯‮h, "" + c⁯‮h);
```

Most IDEs will help beginners write code which follows conventions.  The only problem with this is most developers don't know how to make full use of their IDEs. ;)

Comment: To not break existing code is an argument. But Gosling and his mates enforced the conventions from the beginning. Why did they shy away from making it a syntax rule?

Comment: @wero actually there are classes still in the JDK which didn't follow Convention.  It's Hashtable not HashTable  Java 6 even had straight out bugs like `hashcode` instead of `hashCode`  ByteBuffer doesn't add `get` and `set` to the start of getters and setter, a style i prefer.

Comment: @wero the only enforced convention in Java 8 is that you can't have a lambda variable called `$`, but you can have `$$` or `_`

Comment: @bayou.io correct, got it the wrong way around `$` and `__` are ok but not `_`

Answer (score 2):

Well, personally I think the reason for not enforcing conventions is simply because of the fact because it's technically not really necessary. Counterexample: E.g. in Java you have to name the class file exactly like the class because the Java Class Loader could not load it otherwise. Building these checks into the compiler would bloat the source code and as the name tells it, a compiler converts source code into machine code / byte code / whatever by parsing the source files and checking the syntax. Checking whether a class starts with an uppercase or lowercase letter is simply not the compiler's job.

And of course a programming language gives you a certain degree of freedom by not enforcing such things as conventions to style your code how you like it if it matches the syntax rules of the language.

Comment: The compiler checks syntax rules for names. E.g. a Java class identifier may not start with a digit. To make it check that a Java class starts with an uppercase character would not be a deal...

Comment: @wero That's not a syntax rule, and it isn't 'enforced'. It is a lexical rule, and it is *used* to *determine* where identifiers start and stop.

Answer (score 2):

> From the Java language designers point of view: Is there any good reason to leave a gap between syntax and naming conventions which should never be violated?

Yes. "Never" is a strong word.

The language has requirements and recommendations. [The language specification for identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) is a requirement. But those strong naming conventions are recommendations.

Having some definition of identifiers is necessary for the compiler to recognize them as tokens. Leaving that definition looser than the norm gives us a little freedom for cases outside the norm.

> Are there any meaningful use cases for namings (of classes, methods, fields, variables) which violate the convention but make sense beyond the convention?

Yes. Java programs can interact with other languages, which have different conventions.

**Code conversion**

Sometimes when hand-converting code from another language, leaving the original case is easier and more understandable.

**Code generation**

Sometimes we generate code from a specification that was not written for Java. For example, we might generate code from a [WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) file, or generate wrappers using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

**Code wrappers**

Some Java methods can wrap external functions. For example, [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) allows defining interfaces with a native function's name and signature.

**JVM languages**

[Multiple languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) can run atop the Java virtual machine. These other languages have their own conventions. It's possible to mix languages in a single program. Stepping outside the convention can be necessary to interact.

Comment: interesting arguments. But the interaction could ask for e.g. a class name which starts with a digit so there have to be other means to be interoperable.

Comment: That's true. But most languages don't support identifiers that start with a digit. We get benefit from the freedom in a fraction of cases outside the norm, even if we don't get benefit in a very small fraction of that fraction. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I use some Chinese characters in identifiers, there are no upper/lower cases for them:) So the convention cannot be always enforced.

Of course, it's pretty safe to bet that 99.9% Java code are in English. And you may also argue that the enforcement can be limited on some charsets only.

I agree that this naming convention has become critical, and it should be strictly followed. A java source code that does not follow the convention is practically incomprehensible.

Comment: Great reminder, uppercase/lowercase is cultural. But maybe we could make an exception rule for chinese identifiers...

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is why it's only conventions and not rules... I don't see why should it be enforced, there are many other conventions which are not enforced (e.g. putting constructors before alother methods, putting public methods before private methods and many more), it would be too strict (in my mind at least) to enforce it all.
I can think of one case you don't want this convention to be enforced - it's also common to write consts variable in uppercase- again, just a convention.

In any case, I think that in most IDE's you can configure it to give a warning when such conventions are violated. this can help you I guess

Comment: Good argument: there are many debatable conventions, you cannot enforce them all. But I made a case for the most basic conventions, e.g. the uppercase/lowercase naming rule.

Comment: The way I see it, conventions should make the code readable for humans, syntax should make it readable for compilers. as Long as the compiler can 'understand' your code without it- it's a convention and shouldn't be enforced